# How can I change the default icon of a java application on a mac using netbeans?

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, icons

I have a java application that will need to be deployed on both windows and mac.  On windows, I've configured the system to use a .png file as the icon for the application, but the mac requires an icns file.  I've created the icns file, but I can't figure out how to set that as the icon to use for the application (in the dock, expose, etc).  I'd also need the PC side to ignore that icon assignment.

How can I do this in netbeans?

EDIT: I added have this line in my build.xml file, as per [this link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqExecutableIcon):

```
<property name="app.icon.icns" value="${dist.dir}/Mac64/yellowMac.icns"/>
```

and the yellowMac.icns file is in the same directory as the .jar file, still no joy.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I tried using that property as well, to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Call this inside the constructor

```
//For Microsoft Windows
setIconImage(new ImageIcon("Football.png").getImage());
//For Mac OS X
Application.getApplication().setDockIconImage(new ImageIcon("Football.png").getImage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you deploy your application with Java WebStart then the  snippet in the JNLP file allows for creating a proper Mac app including the icon.

Answer (score 0):

For Netbeans 8.0.2 you can set the .icns file for the Mac OS X bundle when Netbeans builds the native DMG package.

Make sure your .icns file has all of the required icons for a Mac OS X application bundle.

Then...

- Right click on the project and select
  **Properties**
- Under **Build** -> **Deployment**
- select **Enable Native Packaging**
- Click on the **Icons and Splash Image: Native** -> **Edit...**  button
- Enter a (relative) file location to your .icns file in
  the **Native Package Icon:** textfield.
- Hit all of the required
  **OK**s.
- Right click on you project
- select **Package as** -> **DMG Image**

Wait a while until it says *BUILD SUCCESSFUL*.
The .dmg file will be in the *dist/bundles* directory.

Comment: See... OS X Human Interface Guidelines [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Designing.html) for information about required icon resolutions within .icns file.

Comment: I don't see "Build -> Deployment" under my project's Properties.

Comment: @randyM.Roberts there is no Icons and Splash Image button, any ideas? dont understand why its so difficult

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a line to the file `nbproject/project.properties`:

```
app.icon.icns=yellowMac.icns
```

When building the Mac OSX Installer, this icns file was correctly copied over to the `.app`.

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone faces this problem
try this

```
<property name="deploy.icon.native" value="p.icns"/>
```

where p.icns is inside the project base directory